# Sort tree recursively based on two properties

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I have a tree like this:

```
var children = [
    {
        label: 'Foo',
        children: [ ... ]
    }
    ...
];
```

I need to sort it with two constraints:

1. Nodes with children come first and sorted within themselves
2. Nodes without children come second and sorted within themselves

The number of children is irrelevant as long as it's greater than 0.

So, if original tree is represented like this:

```
Foo.0
Sou.2
    Zorro.0
    Amba.0
Book.0
Bud.1
    Ram.0
```

When sorted it looks like this:

```
Bud.1
    Ram.0
Sou.2
    Amba.0
    Zorro.0
Book.0
Foo.0
```

So, I came up with two recursive solutions:

The first one simply applies built-in sorting function :

```
function sortFn(a, b) {
    var aHasChildren = a.children.length,
        bHasChildren = b.children.length;

    if (aHasChildren && bHasChildren || !aHasChildren && !bHasChildren) {
        return a.label.localeCompare(b.label);
    } else {
        return aHasChildren ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

function sortNodesAndChildren(nodes) {
    return nodes
        .sort(sortFn)
        .forEach(function (node) {
            if (node.children.length) {
                sortNodesAndChildren(node.children);
            }
        })
}
```

The second one uses additional arrays kept in sorted order and inserts elements into these arrays using linear insertion sort:

```
function sort(nodes) {
    var a = [];
    var b = [];

    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        if (node.children.length === 0) {
            insert(a, node);
        } else {
            insert(b, node);
            node.children = sort(node.children);
        }
    });

    return b.concat(a);
}


function insert(a, o, property) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (o.label.localeCompare(a[i].label) === -1) {
            a.splice(i, 0, o);
            return;
        }
    }

    a.push(o);
}
```

The second implementation shows considerably worse results in jsperf. But I think they should be compared using complexity, not performance. So I have two questions:

1. Is the second implementation worse in terms of algorithmic complexity?
2. Is there a better way to accomplish the task other than what I came up with?

Comment: The first one seems to be O(n log n) (cannot improve further complexity-wise) while the 2nd one has the same complexity as insertion sort which is O(n^2) or maybe even worse because the splicing in of the element could be O(n) and then it would be O(n^3).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com.